# ADInvalidCredentialException with PowerShell remote management for Exchange 2010

Tags: powershell, exchange-server, powershell-remoting, exchange-server-2010, invoke-command

(My English is bad)
Hi Techies,

I am trying to get Mailbox statistics using Remote PowerShell with cmd executed as an Administrator.

```
powershell -command "$session=New-PSSession -ComputerName 'EX2' -Credential $cred; invoke-command -Session $session -ScriptBlock { Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.Exchange.Management.PowerShell.E2010; dir env:}"
```

this command is ok,

[image: command output]

but I change the command to `Get-MailboxDatabase`

```
powershell -command "$session=New-PSSession -ComputerName 'EX2' -Credential $cred; invoke-command -Session $session -ScriptBlock { Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.Exchange.Management.PowerShell.E2010; Get-MailboxDatabase -Status}"
```

I get an `ADInvalidCredentialException`:

[image: error output]

Answer (score 1):

You have to connect to Exchange Server as follows:

```
$Session = New-PSSession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -ConnectionUri http://<ServerFQDN>/PowerShell/ -Authentication Kerberos -Credential $UserCredential
```

see [Microsoft Docs article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/exchange/exchange-server/connect-to-exchange-servers-using-remote-powershell)

And then either:

a)

```
Import-PSSession $Session -DisableNameChecking
Get-Mailbox
```

b)

```
Invoke-Command -Session $Session -ScriptBlock { Get-Mailbox }
```